# org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: test_table)

Tags: java, sqlite

I use SQLite with Maven and Java8. I am able to create database and tables. But when I do a select query it is throwing exception on `PreaparedStatement`:

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: test_table)

My database file is in "D:/Clients/Client1/sqlite/clientDb.db".

```
public boolean testSelectQuery(String val1, String val2) {
    
    String sql = "SELECT  *FROM test_table WHERE col1 = ? and col2 = ? ";
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:/Clients/Client1/sqlite/clientDb.db");
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);**// Throwing exception**
        // set the value
        pstmt.setString(1, val1);
        pstmt.setString(2, val2);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery(sql);
        return rs.isBeforeFirst();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        //close resources
    }          
}
```

I tried adding database name before table like `database.table_name` but it's not working.

Comment: `"jdbc:sqlite:D:\Clients\Client1\sqlite\clientdb.db"` you should escape those backslashes: `"jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Clients\\Client1\\sqlite\\clientdb.db"`

Comment: But it's able to create table with same connection string

Comment: That string doesn't even compile on my machine. So are you sure that's your actual code (or, even better, a [example])?

Comment: I updated my code with connection string, "jdbc:sqlite:D:/Clients/Client1/sqlite/clientDb.db"